# get string of elements by name

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I'm newbee in JS so i need your help.

I have this JSON code :

```
{
    "data": {
        "people": [

            "get_my_obj": [
                {
                    "yearcome": 2006,
                    "email": "email1@test.com",
                    "came": "1.12",
                    "name": "Alex "
                },
                {
                    "yearcome": 2010,
                    "email": "email2@test.com",
                    "came": "1.12",
                    "name": "John"
                },
                {
                    "yearcome": 2012,
                    "email": "email3@test.com",
                    "came": "1.12",
                    "name": "Max"
                }

            ]
                }
}
```

How i can get string of elements with emails? 
For example var a = email1@test.com;email2@test.com;email3@test.com;

Thats really hard for me because if i have only 2 objects so string must show 2 emails if 3 objects show 3 emails.

Please help me find the way how to do it

Comment: I'd suggest you research how to read JSON, javascript loops, and how to append to a variable. Come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = { data: ....};
var mails = s.data.people.get_my_obj.map(function (e) { return e.email; }).join(';');
console.log(mails);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It works if data doesn't change.But it can be changed and not always can be 3 objects in get_my_obj.

Comment: If the data changes you have to rerun the map(), no matter how many objects get_my_obj has.

Comment: But i cannot change var s every time when data changes.